# QT + OpenCV no Mac Os 10.10.3 com error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Eu instalei recentemente o Qt Creator e OpenCv. Consegui compilar tranquilamente o QT e o OpenCv separados. Mas não consigo compilar ambos juntos. Meu arquivo `.pro` está assim:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-06-27T12:52:47 
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Older
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_objdetect \
-lopencv_calib3d



QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-stdlib=libc++

QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-std=c++11
QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-stdlib=libc++

QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
```

O problema é que se eu deixar o arquivo main.cpp deste modo compila normalmente:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Se eu adicionar essa única linha eu recebo o erro *"error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"*:

```
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("/Users/pedrosoares/TESTEOpenCV/fefafofauroFex.png");
```

Já fiz de tudo, tudo que é tipo de fórum mas nenhum funcionou no meu mac.

Comment: Uma vez eu compilei pelo terminal utilizando o arquivo CMakeLists.txt. E ele está na pasta /usr/local/lib

Comment: Estou compilando para x86_64. Acabei de adicionar o INCLUDE que me disse e ainda recebo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Sim, o mesmo erro. Esqueci de mencionar e após o erro do x86_64, aparece também o erro "error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Pedro eu ofereci uma recompensa de 100 pontos para quem responder, espero que isto lhe ajude a obter a respostas desejada. Boa sorte

Comment: Qual a versão do OSX e Xcode?

Comment: OS 10.10.3 e Xcode 6.3.1, mas estou usando o QT Creator

Comment: Experimenta adicionar apenas o seguinte ao teu ficheiro .pro: CONFIG += c++11.
MUITO IMPORTANTE: Nao te esquecas de fazer clean e rebuild do projecto.

Comment: E ai, conseguiu resolver? Se ainda não, eu também posso oferecer mais uma recompensa pra tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Situações que você pode tentar para o problema com o OpenVC:

- Adicionar ao `LDFLAGS` como sugerido nesta resposta [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781262/1518921)

  ```
  LDFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc
  ```

Situações que pode tentar para problemas com o compilador do MAC:

- Modificar o `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, como sugerido no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119190/1518921)

  Edite `/Applications/Qt/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf` e troque a linha:

  ```
  QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
  ```

  por:

  ```
  QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9
  ```
- Usar `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` e `QMAKE_LFLAGS` Conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18019320/1518921):

  ```
  mac: CONFIG += MAC_CONFIG

  MAC_CONFIG {
      QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
      QMAKE_LFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
  }
  ```

Comment: Fiz e continuei recebendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você tentou editar o `/Applications/Qt/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf` ou fez isto apenas no .pro, tente em ambos?

Comment: Fiz em ambos. tanto no qmake.conf quanto no .pro

Comment: Está complicado rs... eu não tenho um Mac pra testar, mas vou tentar encontrar a resposta, acredito que logo durante a semana possa aparecer outras respostas. +1 pra sua pergunta